# NoSuchMethodFound during swipe image android

Tags: android, image, swipe

I have created the  swipe image functionality. It is working fine on nexus, and small screen phone. but when i run it on 7' tab or 10' screen it throw nosuchmethod error on (event.getAxisValue): below is the code

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {    
 float endXValue = 0;

 //ERROR is THROWING ON THIS LINE
 float x1 = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
 int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

 switch (action) {
     case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
         startXValue = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
         return true;

     case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
         endXValue = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
         if (endXValue > startXValue) {
             if (endXValue - startXValue > 100) {
                 System.out.println("Left-Right");
                 count--;
                 int imageId = getImageViewId("prev");
                 imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

             }
         }else {
             if (startXValue -endXValue> 100) {
                 System.out.println("Right-Left");
                 int imageId = getImageViewId("next");
                 imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
                 count++;
            }
         }
         return true;
       default:
         return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
```

}

I am using API19

Comment: getAxisValue (int axis) Added in API level 12. Are your tablets have API number 12 or greater?

Comment: Thanks, It was API Level 8. I have make the changes in emulator for API 19 and its working. But do we have any other alternative so that swipe will work on API 8 level devices as well?

Comment: Do you know about ViewPager? you can swipe images and other views with it.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html